# Handle individual clicks on elements with recycleView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Im building a simple aplication with a recycleView/CardLayout, i followeed [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) tutorial.

I see many questions answered for the card click, but what i need is to handle diferent actions when the user clicks the title or the user clicks on the image **in each card**.

This is what i have at the moment:

```
public class SimiliarPlantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimiliarPlantsAdapter.PlantViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Plant> plants = new ArrayList<Plant>();
    Context context;

    public static class PlantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView plantName;
        CheckBox plantCheck;
        ImageView plantPhoto;

        PlantViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            plantName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantName);
            plantCheck = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantCheck);
            plantPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantPhoto);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public PlantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.similiar_photo_row, viewGroup, false);
        PlantViewHolder pvh = new PlantViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlantViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.plantName.setText(plants.get(position).getSpecie());
        holder.plantCheck.setText("Are you sure this is the plant?");


        Log.d("foto",String.valueOf(holder.plantName));


        String urlFoto = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/images/" + holder.plantName.getText().toString() + "/Thumbnail.jpg";
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(urlFoto)
                .resize(250, 250)
                .into(holder.plantPhoto);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return plants.size();
    }

    public SimiliarPlantsAdapter(ArrayList<Plant> plants,Context context) {
        this.plants = plants;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

**MY Activity**

```
public class SimiliarPhotos extends AppCompatActivity implements IResult {

    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    ArrayList<Plant> plants = new ArrayList<Plant>();
    SimiliarPlantsAdapter adapter;

    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String GETREQUEST = "GETCALL";

    //login url connection
    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/plants";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_similiar_photos);

        rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);


        initializeAdapter();

        initVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL);
    }


    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("resposta",response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
        Log.d("resposta",response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("resposta",error.toString());
    }

    void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                Plant plant;
                Log.d("ENTERED","ENTEREDHERE1");
                // iterate over the JSONArray response
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i); // get the individual object from JSONArray
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("id")); // get the unique identifier from the object
                        String specie = object.getString("specie"); // get the name of the specie from the object
                        String description = object.getString("description"); // get the description of the object
                        plant = new Plant(id,specie,description); // construct the object
                        Log.d("plant",String.valueOf(plant));
                        plants.add(plant); // add the object to the arraylist so it can be used on the cardLayout

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("ENTERED",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("resposta",error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public void initializeAdapter(){
        Log.d("plants",String.valueOf(plants.size()));
        adapter = new SimiliarPlantsAdapter(plants,SimiliarPhotos.this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

The volley init is the request, not so important for the question, since i get the data correctly

Comment: put your activity code here

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to add the interface to handle the clicks in your `Adapter` and add it in your constructor :

```
    public class SimiliarPlantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimiliarPlantsAdapter.PlantViewHolder>{

  private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onTitleClicked(int position, String title, View clickedview);
            void onImageClicked(int position, View clickedview);
        }

    }
    public SimiliarPlantsAdapter(ArrayList<Plant> plants,Context context, OnItemClickListener listener ) {
        this.plants = plants;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

Now, you have to set these on your `onClick` method inside your `onBindViewHolder`:

```
 holder.plantName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                        onItemClickListener.onTitleClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition(), plants.get(position).getSpecie(), view);
                    }
                }
            });

 holder.plantPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                        onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition(), view);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And finally, implement the interface in your `Activity`:

```
    public class SimiliarPhotos extends AppCompatActivity implements IResult, SimiliarPlantsAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

     @Override
        public void onTitleClicked(int position, String title, View clickedView) {
           //Handle your title click here
        }

      @Override
        public void onImageClicked(int position, View clickedView) {
            //Handle your image click here
        }

 public void initializeAdapter(){
        Log.d("plants",String.valueOf(plants.size()));
        adapter = new SimiliarPlantsAdapter(plants,SimiliarPhotos.this, SimilarPhotos.this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Comment: i didn't complet your answer it seems fine, but say me something the onitemclicklistener is your listener right? Thank you

Comment: yes, the onItemClickListener is your listener and you have to use it in your activity to handle the clicks in your title and your image

Comment: thank you i will accept it, i just need 1 more thing, now my adapter need 1 more parameter it is the callback, how can i pass it?

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, I forgot this, I will edit my answer, check it again.

Comment: Sorry if i am annoying but i created the same for a checkbox toogle, i want to uncheck it with a builder do you know how to access the checkbox inside the listener?

Comment: yes, you can do that,  ask a new question and I answer it for you

Comment: did it, it is similliar, changed some things